# First order ODE with unique solution can't be solved. Any workaround?

Tags: differential-equations

This first order ode
\begin{align*}
y'&= \frac{\cos(y)}{x}\\ 
y(1)&=\pi
\end{align*}
By [existence and uniqueness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) has solution and the solution is unique (on interval that include the initial point.

We see that $y'=\frac{\cos(y)}{x}=f(x,y)$. We see that $f$ is defined for all $y$ and all $x$ except $x=0$, and $f_y$ is also defined for all $y$ and all $x$ except $x=0$. Since initial conditions is not at $x=0$, then theory say that solution exists and is unique on some interval that includes the point $(1,\pi)$. So Mathematica should be able to find it.

But `DSolve` does not give a solution at all. Could someone come with a workaround?

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == Cos[y[x]]/x, y[1] == Pi}, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the solution curve using Stream plot passing through IC

```
StreamPlot[{1,Cos[y]/x},{x,0,4},{y,0,2*Pi},
     StreamPoints->{{{{1,Pi},Thickness[.01]},Automatic}},ImagePadding->2,
     Epilog->{Red,PointSize[.05],Point[{{1,Pi}}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the solution using `NDSolve`

```
sol=NDSolve[{y'[x]==Cos[y[x]]/x,y[1]==Pi},y,{x,$MachineEpsilon,4}]
Plot[Evaluate[y[x]/.sol],{x,0,4},AxesOrigin->{0,0},
        Epilog->{Red,PointSize[.05],Point[{{1,Pi}}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any one knows why Mathematica does not solve this?

Btw, the analytical solution given by Maple is

```
ode:=diff(y(x), x) = cos(y(x))/x;
dsolve([ode,y(1)=Pi])
```

\begin{align*}
y = \arctan \left(\frac{x^{2}-1}{x^{2}+1}, -\frac{2 x}{x^{2}+1}\right)
\end{align*}

Using the normal definition of $\arctan(y,x)$ and not Mathematica's defintion of $\arctan(x,y)$  However, when I Plot Maple's solution it is not continuous at $x=1$. So may be Maple's solution also has problem:

```
 plot(arctan((x^2 - 1)/(x^2 + 1), -2*x/(x^2 + 1)),x=0..3)
```

[image]

V 13.3.1 on windows 10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inverse problem is solved without problems

```
solx = DSolve[{x[y] == Cos[y ] x'[y], x[Pi] == 1}, x, y ][[1]]
(*{x -> Function[{y}, -E^(2 ArcTanh[Tan[y/2]])]}*)

ParametricPlot[{x[y], y} /. solx, {y, -3, 3},PlotRange -> {{0, Pi}, {-Pi, Pi}}, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

Comment: How do you explain the discontinuity in the plot?

Comment: ode is singular for `y->Pi/2` . In other words `Limit[y[x],Abs[x->Infinity]==Pi/2`

Comment: The horizontal asymptote is also plotted  as a point  at infinity outside the given domain. right?

Comment: What about the discontinuity at $x=1$, which is at the initial condition $x=1$, $y=\pi$ where the ODE is not singular? The inverse problem seems to have a problem.

Comment: It is a graphics replot of the given point $(1,\pi)$ indicated as a check.

Comment: @Goofy The solution of the inverse problem has periodicity 2Pi : `x[y]==x[y+2 Pi]`

Comment: Why don't you show `ParametricPlot[{x[y], y} /. solx, {y, 1.6, 3 Pi/2}]`, in that case? Instead of the one with the gap discontinuity. It's confusing. And one still has the problem `x[Pi] /. solx` does not yield `1` (the initial condition).

Comment: @Goofy Point `{1,Pi}`  is indeed included! I don't know how to force `DSolve`  to   evaluate continous solutions

Comment: That's what I mean: How to get Mathematica to include the point `{1, Pi}` in the formula it produces — it doesn't seem to be an easy problem to fix.

Comment: @Goofy Again: Point `{1,Pi}` is included, but solution shows a branch cut

Comment: Again: Point `{1, Pi}` is ***not*** included in the solution `solx` above. I thought this was clear. I agree that `{1, Pi}` is included in the true mathematical solution, but  `x[Pi] /. solx` evaluates to `Indeterminate`, not `1`. I am beginning to think you mean something else by "Point {1,Pi} is included": for instance, that `x[Pi] /. solx` evaluates to a numeric value for you. (I'm using V13.3, in case it's a version issue. But I doubt it is, since `Tan[y/2]` is undefined at `y = Pi`.)

Comment: Try `Limit[x[y] /. solx, y -> Pi] == 1`

Comment: Exactly. That is what I mean. It is not included. It's limit only.

Answer (score 3):

By hand separable method, after substitution $u = \sin(y/2)$:

```
Integrate[2/((1 - 2 u[x]^2) Sqrt[1 - u[x]^2]), {u[x], 1, Sin[Y/2]}, 
  Assumptions -> {1/2 < Y < 3/2}] == 
 Integrate[1/x, {x, 1, X}, Assumptions -> {0 < X}]

(* 2 ArcCoth[Tan[Y/2]] == Log[X] *)

ContourPlot[2 ArcCoth[Tan[Y/2]] == Log[X],
 {X, $MachineEpsilon, 2}, {Y, Pi/2, 3 Pi/2}]
```

[image]

I don't seem to be able to solve for `Y` without incurring branch-cut problems. Could sort them out by hand, of course.

After some playing around I get this form, which avoids branch cut issues:

```
Y == 2 ArcTan[-1 + X, 1 + X]

{y'[x] == Cos[y[x]]/x, y[1] == Pi} /. 
  y -> Function[x, 2 ArcTan[-1 + x, 1 + x]] // FullSimplify

(* {True, True} *)
```

Okay, here's a workaround, based in ideas springing from the foregoing solution.

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{ArcTan},
 Unprotect@ArcTan;
 ArcTan[Tanh[e_]] := ArcTan[Cosh[e], Sinh[e]];
 Protect@ArcTan;
 dsol = First@DSolve[{y'[x] == Cos[y[x]]/x, y[1] == Pi}, y[x], x] // 
   FullSimplify;
 ]
Plot[y[x] /. dsol, {x, 0, 2}]

(* {y[x] -> 2 ArcTan[I Sinh[Log[x]/2], I Cosh[Log[x]/2]]} *)
```

[image]

You can use `ArcTan[Tanh[e_]] := ArcTan[Cosh[e]/I, Sinh[e]/I]` to get rid of the extraneous pair of `I`s.

Remark on the difficulty: It seems most solutions that can be coaxed out of `DSolve` have something evaluates to infinity at the initial condition when determining the constant of integration. In each case, the entire expression being evaluated has a limit (has the form $\infty/\infty$), but the limit is not used by the solver. And the process fails.

Comment: I get `Y == 2 ArcTan[-1 + X, 1 + X]` fooling around with the solution above.

Comment: How do you switch from `y[x]` to `u[x]`? How about the initial condition `y[1]==Pi`?

Comment: @user64494 Sorry, I forgot to mention the substitution. (Mma does it `{y'[x] == Cos[y[x]]/x, y[1] == Pi} /.  y -> Function[t, 2 ArcSin[u[t]]] // TrigExpand // Simplify`. For a separable IVP $dy/v(y) = dx/w(x), y(x_0) =y_0$, the solution is $\displaystyle\int_{y_0}^y {dy \over v(y)} = \int_{x_0}^x {dx \over w(x)}$. After the substitution, the IC becomes $u(1) = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \frac {dy}{dx}= \frac{\cos y }{x}$$

$$ \int \sec y ~dy =\int\frac {dx}{x}$$

Integrate, include arbitrary constant

$$ \log( \tan (\pi/4+ y/2)) = \log ( C x)$$

$$ y= 2\tan ^{-1} ( Cx) - \pi/2 ;$$

Variable separable ode, solved directly.

The inverse tan function solution has a horizontal asymptote for large enough $x.$

I expected Mathematica should solve it by `DSolve`, with `Reduce`
without numerical `NDSolve`, but sorry, the above  does not answer your question; I was also troubled by inverse trig functions not working with `Reduce`.

EDIT1:

To avoid an inverse function solution we can can find inverse function ode itself as
$$ \frac{-1}{y'(x)} = \frac{\cos x }{y} $$

$$\text{ having solution }  Cy= \tan (\pi/4+x/2) \text{ that should  go through point } (1,\pi/2).$$

Then Mathematica may `DSolve` straight. The $(x,y)$ need to be swapped back.